# php wont display data on index site

Tags: php, html, sh

I have 3 files, one index.php, one instapic.php and one instapic.sh
The php is supposed to execute sh to show an image but it wont work when it is on the "index" site, it worked earlier when it was directed to /instapic.php but i want it to display on main index page.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
font family: Ubuntu;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1> <center> Instagram Full Size Profile Picture </center> </h1>
</div>
<center>
<form action="" method="get">
Enter Instagram Username: <input type="text" name="input">
<input type="submit" value="View">
</form>
</center>
</body>
```

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['input'];
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
$output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/instapic.sh $name");
echo "<img src=$output>";
?>
```

-

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=$1
#curl -s https://www.instagram.com/$NAME/ | grep image | grep fbma | sed 's,s150x150/,,g' | cut -f 4 -f '"'
curl -s https://www.instagram.com/$NAME/ | grep "og:image" | sed 's,s150x150/,,g' | cut -f 4 -f '"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to can add some PHP code on your index and just send your form to the same page.
If you don't want to reload the page every time you have to send an ajax call.
It could be a solution (not the best at all):

Include this at the beginning of you index.php file :

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_REQUEST['input'])) {
    $name = $_REQUEST['input'];
    $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/instapic.sh $name");
  }
>
```

And Include this where you want to display the images :

```
<?php
  if(isset($output)) {
    echo "<img src=$output>";
  }
>
```

Also don't forget to add "index.php' on the action attribute of the form